# Filter lines which not contain in a list

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, unix

When i filter lines which not contain a specified string ,i use 
`grep -v "specifiedstring" filename`
but how to filter lines which not contain many strings in a list .
Thanks much !

Comment: I've deleted my answer now you've explained your problem a little more.  You have 6000 strings you want to exclude.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can `or` multiple strings:

```
grep -v "string1\|string2\|string3" filename
```

This would exclude lines containing `string1`, `string2`, `string3`.

In basic regex (the above version), regex metacharacters lose their special meaning and need to be escaped.

Using extended regex, you don't need to escape the `|`:

```
grep -Ev "string1|string2|string3" filename
```

---

If the list is contained in a file, use `-f` option:

```
grep -v -f list_to_exclude filename
```

---

As mentioned in the comments, if the pattern are a set of strings you could supply the `-F` option in order to speed up `grep`:

```
grep -F -v -f list_to_exclude filename
```

From the manual:

```
   -F, --fixed-strings
          Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
          newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
          POSIX.)
```

The following example should explain it further.  Given an input file, say `input.txt`:

```
This is line.
This is line2.
This is line3.
This is line4.
This is line*.
```

Now using the command:

```
grep -v 'line*' input.txt
```

would not produce any results since the *pattern* `line*` is interpreted as a regular expression and would match all lines in the given input file and `-v` inverts matches.  If `line*` were meant to be a *fixed string* and not a regex, then supplying the `-F` option, i.e. saying:

```
grep -F -v 'line*' input.txt
```

would produce:

```
This is line.
This is line2.
This is line3.
This is line4.
```

Moreover, since `grep` is now not looking for *patterns* but for *fixed strings* it is considerably faster than without using the `-F` option.

Comment: thanks ,but the list is so long ,it is about 6000 lines ,so i save it into list.txt .I thinks write one by one and separate by `| ` is not a good solution

Comment: @YOU If the list is contained in a file, use `-f`.  Refer to the edit above.

Comment: It seems the data i want to filter out is too large ,the process automatically KILLED

Comment: @YOU How big are the files?  Try passing `-F` too: `grep -F -v -f list filename`

Comment: what does -F means? ,the filter file contain about 3000000 lines and the exclude is 6000 line ,the size of filter file about 223mb .let i try your new way .

Comment: @YOU `-F` causes `grep` to interpret the pattern as fixed strings not as a regex and is thus faster.

Comment: did you try that command ,i use ,but nothing happen ,the output is still the original file

Comment: Thanks .i did it with option -F .

Comment: @YOU And it would have been faster.  Is that correct?

Comment: yes ,it really so so fast ,without -F ,i spend much time to wait but it still not finish the job .can you explain more about "fixed string not as regex",can you give an example

Comment: If `list_to_exclude` is empty, this fails for me. Looks like it's intended, since an empty line in `list_to_exclude` matches any line in `filename`. Have you got any ideas how to deal with potentially empty exclusion list?

Answer (score 3):

You can `AND` several strings with grep

```
grep -v "string1.*string2" file
```

This will filter out lines containing both string1 and string2 while leaving lines that contain either just string1 or string2

Answer (score 2):

If you get the lists **from other commands** and not from files:

```
grep -F -v -f <(get_list_to_exclude) <(get_list_to_filter)
```

> note: **grep fails if the exclusion output is empty** (since a single empty line matches any line in filtered list).

If lists are **sorted**, the `comm` utility can be used. It **doesn't fail with an empty exclusion list**.

> comm -- select or reject lines common to two files

Two example files:

```
$ cat a
a
b
c
$ cat b
a
z
```

`comm` can filter lists in the following way:

```
# exclude b from a
$ comm -2 -3 a b
b
c


# exclude a from b
$ comm -1 -3 a b
z
```

Same syntax for streams :

```
$ comm -2 -3 <(cat a) <(cat b)
b
c
```

see `man comm` for more instructions.

<sub>Translated from [StackOverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/438528/181472)</sub>